# Calling out for help from all quarters for a near-magical transformation

Tags: weight-loss, personal-training, conditioning

I am a wannabe fitness freak... Right now I am an overweight, almost obese, completely lazy, low self esteemed low-life with a dream of "magically" transforming myself into a fitness fanatic.

Foolishly enough, I got involved in a bet that requires me to lose around 20 kilos in a year!

The bet is the least of my concerns and I understand I have multiple issues that need sorting at various levels.

This is exactly what motivated me to accept the bet in the first place. I am sure that losing weight would be the first step of my transformation (I realize that we do not live in a fairyland and working on my issues is the only solution).

I am 26 years old, 6' 2" tall and weigh around 105 kilos currently. I am a smoker (a pack a day) and a drinker (2-3 times a week). I lead a complete sedentary lifestyle, with absolutely zero stamina, endurance, energy and focus.

My dream is to be a fit and healthy (mentally and physically) person with completely toned body (as complete as having 12 pack abs) and mind. I am looking forward to have a completely conditioned body that can survive in any tough, rough, difficult-to-live conditions.

Having said that, my first target is to achieve a weight loss of 20 kilos in a year. If my dream can somehow fit into this, I would be more than happy. Otherwise, I am planning to chase my dream after the weight loss.

I know that there is a wrold of difference in where I dream to be and where I stand currently. But I am a born dreamer.

I need help with nutrition, exercises, fitness plans, scheduling (and personality development?).

Please help me.

Comment: [I'd encourage you to drop by in our chatroom - (link)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/324), your question is far too broad, so it would be good if we could help you get more focused and have you ask a more specific question. There are plenty of questions on our site about getting started, which should give you a heads up in the right direction. As it stands right now though, this question is too vague to be answered.

Comment: The goals are not impossible.  I lost about 38kg in 7 months.  But you can't continue being the same way you are now.  There's plenty of other questions around here that can help you fine tune your goals and form a plan of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is lose weight, all you really need is a weekly amphetamine binge.

Your goals are the wrong way round. Concentrate on being healthy first. The weight loss will naturally occur. Weight loss generally doesn't occur in a straight line. It fluctuates. It is hard to stay focused on a goal that is all over the place.

If you work on health, 20 kilos in a year should be achievable.

Weight loss is achieved through a combination of two elements - diet and exercise.

**Diet**

Diet is by far the most important factor. First of all work out what you are putting in to yourself. For a week write down everything you ingest. How much of it is junk and how much is whole foods? By junk I mean processed - white bread, sugar, basically all the convenience foods. This voyage of discovery will help you become aware of the challenges that lie ahead.

You want to cut out all the junk. Eat only whole foods. [Here](http://nerdfitness.com/blog/2011/11/10/healthy-eating/) is more information.

Booze won't help as that is largely empty calories. If you cut out completely though, you are less likely to succeed in your goal. Just be aware every time you drink of what you are doing to yourself and drink less. As you get healthier your natural desire to get wasted does reduce, so just leave it up to nature...

**Exercise**

Exercise (cardiovascular) for losing weight is overrated. You have to sit on a rowing machine for 20 minutes just to work off a pint of beer. Don't have any preconceptions that you can just run for 15 minutes a day to work off that massive pile of fast food you are about to eat.

However, exercise for health and happiness is vital. The more you exercise the better you feel about yourself and the more likely you are to stick to a whole food diet.

Your first goal will be to just get yourself moving. I would recommend a [Couch to 5K program](http://www.coolrunning.com/engine/2/2_3/181.shtml). This will get you running 5 kilometres in 9 weeks.

Once you are a fair way into the running program and are less sedentary you are ready to turn to the iron.

Unfortunately you set the bet to lose weight rather than just body fat. The best exercise for losing body fat is weight lifting. As you build up muscle your body needs more energy to maintain itself and burns off yer fat. Unfortunately as you build up muscle you get heavier. However, it is still well worth doing. You will just have to lose more fat than you gain muscle. As a beginner this is certainly doable - advanced bodybuilders struggle here.

If you can join a gym, I recommend looking into the [Strong Lifts](http://stronglifts.com/) program. It is designed for beginners and won't take up much of your time.

If you don't want to do this have a look at [Convict Conditioning](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Convict-Conditioning-Weakness-Survival-Strength/dp/0938045768/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1330086718&sr=8-1). It is a strength training program using minimal equipment taking you from beginner to advanced.

Whatever you do, don't let anyone tell you to do loads of sit ups. They do not work.

Comment: Hi @Dreadlift, I kind of feel lousy for closing the question, because your answer includes a lot of useful resources. Perhaps you'd be interested in helping out with our blog to give this kind of content a new home? [Perhaps you should drop by in our chat room some time!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/324/the-locker-room)

Comment: Thx Dreadlift... Somehow, I feel that this is what I needed...

Comment: @Dreadlift Definitely pop into chat! We are always looking for volunteers to help out with the blog as well!

Comment: @IvoFlipse, Technically I'm supposed to be working, so can't really pop into the chat. ;-) I would love to help out with the blog though if there was something useful I could contribute. Please let me know what I could do.

Comment: @Dreadlift there isn't a hurry, so you can drop into the chat room whenever you have the time. But the basic gist is we make you an account, you write a draft which gets reviewed and most likely then it'll get published :-) You can basically write about anything that would interest you or our community

Answer (score 0):

Dedication and determination.......as long as you have those, everything else become tough, but do-able.  I'm not sure of your financial resources, but would recommend joining a local gym, finding a personal trainer to start you on a program and getting involved in some local self-help groups for smoking and drinking (even though it doesn't sound like you drink excessively).

Find out what will motivate you over the long term and keep you active. It could be a sport you want to participate in, camping, cycling, etc....but something that really interests you that will make the steps you're taking with exercising, etc. more meaningful.

good luck

Comment: Thanks, Maede. Yes, I am considering all these. I am also looking at the various specific things that I should be doing. Like, the fitness plan to follow, what kind of exercises to do, the diet (I am a vegetarian), should it be achieved through cardio only or with a combination of cardio and weight training, what are the specific exercises that I should do... all these with the initial weightloss in mind plus the "bigger dream"...